# Can I run a git repository on an encrypted drive which contains files other users can read?

Tags: git, encryption

I have an encrypted home directory, and a git repository therein.

I have a non-encrypted /var/www (actually symlinked to another drive) which I want to include in the version control.

If I host the web site's source in the git repository, the web server can't read them as it's running as a different user and the files appear to be encrypted.

I want the rest of the repository to be subject to encryption as is everything else within my home directory.

I don't want to manually sync the files, or otherwise duplicate them.

Are these goals compatible?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want, from reading the question.  Do you want a Git repository which is partially encrypted?

Comment: How are the existing repository and the `/var/www/` related logically? I'm having trouble understanding why you want them in the same repository.

Comment: Deitrich, that's not my goal. I want my home directory to be encrypted, I want my repository to be in my home directory, I want at least part of my repository to be readable by another user (the web server).

Comment: Chris, `/var/www` is related to the repository only insofar as the repository contains the web pages and `/var/www` idiomatically points to the web pages. Setting up Apache to look in `/home/me/www/foo` would be fine, except that it doesn't work because I have an encrypted home partition.